# Prevent json.dumps from converting to unicode

Tags: json, python-2.7, utf-8

I noticed that json.dumps always converts string to UTF-8, how can I prevent this from happening? Should I encode and decode the values myself? Here's the use case, I'd like x['a'] and y['a'] to be the same.

```
x = {'a': '\xc3\xa6', 'b':u'æ', 'c':u'\xe6'}
print type(x['a']), x
 <type 'str'> {'a': '\xc3\xa6', 'c': u'\xe6', 'b': u'\xe6'}
t = json.dumps(x)
print type(t),t
 <type 'str'> {"a": "\u00e6", "c": "\u00e6", "b": "\u00e6"}
y = json.loads(t)
print type(y['a']),y
 <type 'unicode'> {u'a': u'\xe6', u'c': u'\xe6', u'b': u'\xe6'}
```

Comment: JSON strings can represent any Unicode character, so using Python's `unicode` type is the natural choice. If you want to have bytes (Python 2's `str`), then – according to the Zen of Python – encoding explicitly is better than relying on some implicit coercion (as is happening with `'\xc3\xa6'` in the first step).

Comment: Why do you want to have `str` anyway? If it's just the `u` prefix annoying you, then upgrading to Python 3 is probably the best option.

Comment: How would you want `'\xc3\xa6'` to be represented in JSON anyway? JSON doesn't have a bytes type, so your options are either decoding or converting to an array of integers.

Comment: @lenz I need to send some serialized data structures and I need to maintain the original types on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an object hook that does the encoding for you:

```
>>> x = json.dumps({'a': u'\xe6', u'b': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> x
'{"a": "\\u00e6", "b": [1, 2, 3]}'
>>> json.loads(x, object_hook=no_unicode)
{'a': '\xc3\xa6', 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
```

This hook simply encodes all keys and (if they are strings) values with UTF-8:

```
def no_unicode(obj):
    return {k.encode('utf8'): safe_encode(v)
            for k, v in obj.iteritems()}

def safe_encode(something):
    if isinstance(something, unicode):
        return something.encode('utf8')
    return something
```

However, this solution only works for strings that are direct members of an object. It won't work if the strings are nested inside an array/list:

```
>>> x = json.dumps({'a': [u'\xe6']})
>>> json.loads(x, object_hook=no_unicode)
{'a': [u'\xe6']}
```

or if they are at the top level:

```
>>> x = json.dumps(u'\xe6')
>>> json.loads(x, object_hook=no_unicode)
u'\xe6'
```

The first case can be fixed by extending the hook to recursively descend into containers and attempt to encode any strings encountered.
However, I can't see a way to fix the second case. The `json` doesn't provide hooks for any types other than object (the reason for this might be that, originally, the top-level structure of a JSON fragment had to be an object).

Comment: I just realised I hadn't carefully read your question and you were actually asking for the opposite – what is happening in `json.dumps`, not `json.loads`. However, this method would still meet your requirement of `x['a']` and `y['a']` having the same type.

Comment: Thanks, I got excited and was hoping there was something similar for json.dumps, turns out that setting ensure_ascii=False doesn't work either..

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out another solution, I ended up using `pickle` to serialize specific parts of my data structure which I then send in the `json` request.

```
x = {'a': '\xc3\xa6', 'b':u'æ', 'c':u'\xe6'}
t = pickle.dumps(x)
t = base64.b64encode(t)
print type(t),t
y = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(t))
print type(y['a']),y
```

This correctly prints:

```
<type 'str'> KGRwMApTJ2EnCnAxClMnXHhjM1x4YTYnCnAyCnNTJ2MnCnAzClbmCnA0CnNTJ2InCnA1Cmc0CnMu
<type 'str'> {'a': '\xc3\xa6', 'c': u'\xe6', 'b': u'\xe6'}
```

Comment: Sure, if it's Python on both ends, pickling is the natural thing to do.

Comment: Works for now but I wanted something that would have broader support in the long run. I'm still hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: What needs more light? You can't have both: support for Python's data model (= different types for `str` and `bytes`) and broad support (= support for data models without this distinction, eg. JavaScript).